# jQuery changing CSS inside of a nested function call

Tags: jquery, css, nested-function

I'm currently trying to create a drag and drop element which allows me to move an element which it is attached to. Everything is being created dynamically. I'm having a re-occurring problem where I can't change the css from inside a nested function call.

**jQuery (Not working)**

```
//Drag begin     
var dragX;
var dragY;
var mouseDown = false;
var dragIcon = $('<span>')
.css({
    'z-index' : '11',
    'position' : 'absolute',
    'width' : '300px',
    'height' : '140px',
    'left' : '0px',
    'top' : '20px'
})

.addClass('unselectable')

.mousedown(function(){
    mouseDown = true;
    $(this).mousemove(function(){
        if(mouseDown == true){
            var dragX = getCurrentMouseX();
            var dragY = getCurrentMouseY();

            //Don't allow ideas to be created too close to the border of the page
            if(dragX < 260){
                dragX = 260;
            }else if(dragX > window.innerWidth - 260){
                dragX = window.innerWidth - 260;
            }    

            if(dragY < 160){
                dragY = 160;
            } else if(dragY > window.innerHeight - 450){
                dragY = window.innerHeight - 450;
            }

            $(this).css({
                'left' : dragX - 150,
                'top' : dragY - 81
            });
        }                
    })
})

.mouseout(function(){
    mouseDown = false;
})
.mouseup(function(){
     mouseDown = false;
});
```

I've written the function in JavaScript which works correctly, however i'm trying to convert it to jQuery. The following is the working JavaScript function:

**JavaScript (Working)**

```
        //Drag begin     
    var dragX;
    var dragY;
    var mouseDown = false;

    //TODO: An icon which can be used to drag the cloud around
    var dragIcon = document.createElement('span');
    dragIcon.style.zIndex = "11";
    dragIcon.style.position = "absolute";
    dragIcon.style.width = "300px";
    dragIcon.style.height = "140px";   
    dragIcon.setAttribute('class', 'unselectable');
    dragIcon.style.left = "0px";
    dragIcon.style.top = "20px";
    dragIcon.unselectable = "on";
    dragIcon.style.MozUserSelect = "none";

    dragIcon.onselectstart = function() {return false;}
    dragIcon.onmousedown = function(){
        mouseDown = true;
        dragIcon.onmousemove = function(){
            if(mouseDown == true){
                var dragX = getCurrentMouseX();
                var dragY = getCurrentMouseY();

                if(dragX < 260){
                    dragX = 260;
                }else if(dragX > window.innerWidth - 260){
                    dragX = window.innerWidth - 260;
                }    

                if(dragY < 160){
                    dragY = 160;
                } else if(dragY > window.innerHeight - 450){
                    dragY = window.innerHeight - 450;
                }                           
                cloudStyle.left = dragX  - 150 + "px"; //-150 to make up for the position of the drag icon
                sunRay.style.left = dragX - 220 + "px";
                cloudStyle.top = dragY - 81 + "px"; //-85 to make up for the positioning
                sunRay.style.top = dragY - 250 + "px"; 
            }
        }
    }

    dragIcon.onmouseout = function(){
        mouseDown = false;
    }
    dragIcon.onmouseup = function(){
        mouseDown = false;
    }
```

Can you please point out where i'm going wrong, and whether i'm taking the wrong approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i've found that to replace the existing style I need to do the following...

```
        item.removeAttr("style");            
        item.attr("style", "style goes here!");
```

Removing the style attribute and re-applying seems to work well.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>I think there are several reasons that might be the cause for it to not work. First of all is that when you use the jQuery selector, you don't have to put in the full tag like `$('<span>')` but rather like `$('span')` to select a specific element. For classes its `$('.class')` and for id's `$('#id')`.</strike>

To actually create the element and append it to the body, change

```
// Rest of code
var test = $('<span>').css({
// etc.
```

into

```
// Rest of code
var test = $('<span>').appendTo('body').css({
// etc.
```

Also, after adjusting that, it seems to be going south when you are calling upon the coordinates of the mouse pointer. jQuery's mousemove function also releases some eventdata which you can then easily use to get the coordinates you need, like so:

```
.mousedown(function() {
    mouseDown = true;
    $(this).mousemove(function(e) {
        if (mouseDown == true) {
            var dragX = e.pageX;
            var dragY = e.pageY;

            // The rest of your original code
```

It's hard to help you further without the HTML and CSS as an example, but i think this should definitely get you on your way.

Comment: If you look at the JavaScript equivalent, you'll see that the OP is [creating a new element](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2).